# jQuery: how to set a specific value selection in dropdown when click yes in radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to set a specific value selection in dropdown when click yes in radio button?

so this is is html markup:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li><label id="ribbonPop">
      <input type="radio" name="yesno"> Yes
    </label></li>
  <li><label id="ribbonNoPop">
      <input type="radio" name="yesno"> No
    </label></li>
</ul>
```

and for exmaple this is my markup in dropdown:

```
<select>
<option>no price</option>
<option>with price</option>
</select>
```

and what I want to happen is when I click YES in radio button the value of option should be "with price". how to do that? pls help. many thanks and more power guys!

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me figuring this out. Godbless all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this.

Below is the html code:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li><label id="ribbonPop">
      <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="withprice"> Yes
    </label></li>
  <li><label id="ribbonNoPop">
      <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="noprice"> No
    </label></li>
</ul>

<select id="select-yesno">
<option value="noprice">no price</option>
<option value="withprice">with price</option>
</select>
```

Below is the jquery code:

```
$("input[name=yesno]").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#select-yesno").val(value);
});
```

Please note in order to make this working you still need to include the jquery library which you can download here https://jquery.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to [bind a click event](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to your inputs. Then, in the event handler, you'll need to [grab the value](http://api.jquery.com/val/) of the clicked input. Then, you'll want to assign some values to your option elements, so that you can [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the appropriate option. And finally, you'll want to [set the selected property](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) on that option.

Try making your way through the above, and if it doesn't work, post a code update.

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTML in the question, you could use the following jQuery to achieve the desired behavior:

```
// Cache optimized jQuery object for target <option> element
// so that it does not have to be newly found after each click event
// Select the first <option> element whose text exactly matches the indicated string
var $withPriceOption = $("option").filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() === "with price";
    }).eq(0);

// Initialize click event handler
$("#ribbonPop").find("input").click(function () {
   $withPriceOption.attr("selected", true);
});
```

Note that the solution above works and answers the question as stated, but as some of the other answers have suggested, you should add uniquely identifying HTML attributes to the target elements in order to make the JS A) less coupled with a specific HTML/DOM structure and B) less coupled with specific text. By doing this, you won't have to rely on a specific HTML/DOM structure or specific text when making your jQuery element selections. By reducing the HTML-JS coupling in this way, you make your JS more resilient to changes in the HTML.

For example, try this HTML:

```
<!-- Add id attribute to <select> element and value attributes to its child <option> elements -->
<select id="priceSelect">
    <option value="0">no price</option>
    <option value="1">with price</option>
</select>

<!-- Add value attributes to the radio buttons -->
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
        <label id="ribbonPop">
          <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="1"> Yes
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label id="ribbonNoPop">
           <input type="radio" name="yesno" value="0"> No
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

with this (less coupled) JS:

```
// Cache optimized jQuery object for target <option> element
// so that it does not have to be newly found after each click event
var $withPriceOption = $("#priceSelect").find("[value=1]");

// Initialize click event handler
$("[name=yesno][value=1]").click(function () {
    $withPriceOption.attr("selected", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your text "Yes" and "No" inside span. Here how it's done

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {


    if ($(this).siblings("span").html() == "Yes") {

      $("select").val("with price");

    } else {
      $("select").val("no price");
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>
    <label id="ribbonPop">
      <input type="radio" name="yesno"> <span>Yes</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label id="ribbonNoPop">
      <input type="radio" name="yesno"> <span>No</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>



<select>
  <option>no price</option>
  <option>with price</option>
</select>
```